# My app doesn't appear in Location Settings list in iOS6

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager, ios6

How can I make appear it in that list? Starting location services isn't working. My CLLocationManager don't receive anything in iOS6. Works fine in iOS 4 and 5.

What is happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried everything in plist files, cleans, rebuilds, new targets, configurations, etc, etc, etc. Nothing worked. But FINALLY I've fixed it. I had to create a new Xcode 4.5 project from scratch, reconfigure it, add file by file and framework by framework manually. It seems that my old XCode project had something internally incompatible with last XCode or something... Maybe a bug. I don't know what was happening yet, but I write this here because maybe it can save someone's next 10 hours of work.

Answer (score 1):

Add CFBundleDisplayName to your info.plist (That's what did it for us). While you're there, you may want to add an entry for NSLocationUsageDescription.

Also, you may need to update your CLLocationManagerDelegate with `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`

Comment: Did you try the standard Xcode upgrade tricks? Restart Xcode, clean. Clean, restart machine, build, clean, restart Xcode? :)

Comment: Yes, a lot... but nothing works. This is insane... The damn arrow never appears on the upper right corner and the location service never starts... Am I the only one suffering this issue? :(

Comment: Well, we had the issue, but just adding CFBundleDisplayName fixed it, apparently. I struggled with editing the info.plist though. It couldn't be edited in the project settings pane, only as a plist.